# Understanding what sudo install does

Tags: linux, software-installation, sudo

I'm using Linux SLES distribution. I want to install `minikube` and it says to do:

```
$ curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube
$ sudo install minikube /usr/local/bin
$ rm minikube
```

I have sudo permissions but I want to make sure what `sudo install` does first. If I want to install `minikube` locally in some directory /some/path/to/tmp, and use it from there and then is it possible to remove by just running `rm -rf /some/path/to/tmp`? Also If I install it in `/usr/local/bin`, how to uninstall it?

Comment: Does `man install` help?  That should explain what install does, including the behavior that you get when you run it as you've posted.